# Using AWS step function with a wait state

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions, aws-cost-explorer

I have a requirement where a client submits a job which I would like to execute after 1 hour. For this I am planning to follow the below design:

1. Create a `AWS Step function (Standard workflow)` with 2 state transitions. First is a `Wait` state which will simply wait for 1 hour and then the second state invokes a lambda function which emits an event to an `AWS event bridge`.
2. Once the event is emitted to event bridge further processing performed.

In this design, my question is whether I will be charged for the 1 hour wait time I have in the `Wait` state. Is my understanding that this is not charged and only 2 state transitions per workflow execution is charged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct.  Standard Workflows are [priced](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/pricing/) only on the number of "State transitions".

---

Pricing is different for Standard and Express workflows.  Use the AWS [Pricing Calculator](https://calculator.aws/#/addService) to compare costs for your use case:

**Standard Workflows**

- **State transitions:** A state transition is counted each time a step in your execution is completed.

**Express Workflows**

- **Duration:** Duration is calculated from the time your workflow begins executing until it completes or otherwise terminates, rounded up to the nearest 100 milliseconds.
- **Memory:** Memory consumption is based on the size of a workflow definition, the use of map or parallel states, and the execution (payload) data size.